# Opening Excel in C# - loading time

Tags: performance, excel, interop

If I want to open an Excel file I used this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
```

Its working fine but this takes a long time, is another possibility faster?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend the Open XML SDK from Microsoft. 
You can open Excel Documents without actually having to install or use Excel.